# Error: function template already inherited - with icpc

Tags: c++11, inheritance, constructor, using, icc

I am writing a class that inherits from `std::vector` (*) and I want to be able to construct it in all the ways that are available for its base, so I use

```
#include <vector>

struct B : public std::vector<double>
{
    using std::vector<double>::vector;
};
```

This compiles fine with the g++ and clang, but the Intel compiler gives me (with flag `-std=c++11`)

> error: function template "B::B(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const std::__1::allocator<double> &)" already inherited from "std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double>>"

at the `using` directive.
Any ideas why this is happening and/or how to solve it?

Update: it would seem this is OS dependent, works fine on Linux and Windows platforms but fails on OS X. A discussion is ongoing on the Intel forums.

(*) I don't want to use polymorphism, please avoid "this is bad practice" answers if not directly relevant - there are in fact numerous posts that agree this is acceptable.

Comment: By the way, I checked that although the constructor is marked as "already inherited", without including the `using` it does not compile with icpc. Still clueless.

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that does not depend on standard library headers? That might make the problem reproducible on other systems.

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment. This is as minimal as I could make it so far... Will post if I find a way.
BTW, the example above also fails for me on Linux (CentOS) with icc 14.0.1 and 14.0.5, although it compiles fine with 15.0.3 and 16.0.1 so that's probably related to old versions not fully supporting C++11.